# How to do I add a parameter of type String to a generated java setter using Xtend active annotations?

Tags: java, annotations, xtend

I have the following snippet in my AbstractFieldProcessor.doTransformation override:

```
field.declaringType.addMethod('set'+ field.simpleName.toFirstUpper +'Input' )
    [


        addParameter("values", ########)
        addParameter("keys",field.type)
        body=
        '''
            this.click«field.simpleName.toFirstUpper»();
            «field.simpleName»Input.sendKeys("ABCDEFG");
        '''
    ]
```

How can I generate the parameter of type Strings for the "value" parameter. The field.type is not a String. How can I create a TypeReference for a String?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `TypeReference` referencing type `String` can be obtained using the `TypeReferenceProvider.getString()` method.

In practice you can use the `TransformationContext` interface (because it extends `TypeReferenceProvider`):

```
override doTransform(MutableClassDeclaration annotatedClass, extension TransformationContext context)
{
    // Add field of type String
    annotatedClass.addField("stringField") [
        type = string // Get TypeReference to type String
    ]
}
```

There are other useful methods in `TypeReferenceProvider` to get a `TypeReference` to other often used types, like `getObject()`, `getPrimitiveX()`, etc.

---

To obtain a `TypeReference` to any type in general, first you should find the type then create a `TypeReference` to it. You can use the `TransformationContext` for this as well:

1. Find the type using the `TransformationContext.findTypeGlobally()` or `TransformationContext.findX()` methods.
2. Obtain `TypeReference` by calling `TransformationContext.newTypeReference()`

For example to create a `TypeReference` to `LinkedHashMap<String, Object>` in the `doTransform()` method, you can use

```
LinkedHashMap.findTypeGlobally.newTypeReference(string, object)
```

Comment: Worked. Thank you.